# Mapstruct - Convert Object who contains and interface into himself

Tags: java, spring, dto, mapstruct

i'm using mapstruct for converting an object to another.
Into the object to convert, there's an interface, and mapstruct doesn't like that.

I was able to convert an interface to an object by implementing the default of the method and specifing the implementation to call:

```
public default MessagesList interfaceMapping (Integer not, List<MessageEntity> list) {

    return messToImpl(numNotification, list);
}
```

Now the problem is that i don't know how to do a similar thing that is not a workaround, to convert an internal object signed as interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out a good way to implement a custom code for a single object mapping:

```
@Mapping(target = "sender", expression = "java(new YourClass(null, messageEntity.getSenderType(), messageEntity.getSenderID(), messageEntity.getSenderContact()))")
```

In this way, through the expression you can define a custom code still using mapstruct definitions.

Just in case you could need to import a class not defined as source or target, just remember to annotate the class as following, to allow mapstruct to import the required class:

```
@Mapper(imports = YourClass.class)
```